# rlang: using function argument in default assignment function

Tags: r, rlang

Using `rlang`, I'd like to have a function that works both when directly called and when passed arguments as part of constructing another function argument by default, e.g.:

```
refdf = data.frame(x=1:100, y=runif(100,-1,1))

test.helper <- function(z, df) {
  qz <- enquo(z)
  range(eval_tidy(qz, df))
}
test.helper(y, refdf) # works

test.main <- function(z, df, def = test.helper(z, df)) {
  print(def)
}
test.main(y, refdf)
# doesn't work:  Error in eval_tidy(qz, df) : object 'y' not found
```

If instead, I do

```
refdf = data.frame(x=1:100, y=runif(100,-1,1))

test.helper <- function(z, df) {
  qz <- as_quosure(z)
  range(eval_tidy(qz, df))
}
test.helper(y, refdf)
# doesn't work: Error in is_quosure(x) : object 'y' not found

test.main <- function(z, df, def = test.helper(enquo(z), df)) {
  print(def)
}
test.main(y, refdf)
# now works
```

I feel like I'm missing something about what gets quoted when; is there an alternative syntax I can use to make both work? I know I could define a separate `test.helper_quo` or some such, but I'd really like to use the `test.helper` in the signature (as an extra hint to users about what functions are available).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
library(rlang)

test.helper <- function(z, df) {
  qz <- enquo(z)
  range(eval_tidy(qz, df))
}
test.helper(y, refdf) # works

test.main <- function(z, df, def = test.helper(!!enquo(z), df)) {
  print(def)
}
test.main(y, refdf) # works

# or with rlang >= 0.4.0
test.main <- function(z, df, def = test.helper({{z}}, df)) {
  print(def)
}
test.main(y, refdf) # works
```

Note that in `def`, we need to capture the quosure passed as `z` and then expand that into the the call the `test.helper` so the it's own `enquo` will be able to see the original symbol.

Comment: This works, thanks; can you explain a little why the quote-unquote step is necessary?  The error's suggest that it is indeed finding the right symbol - so what's the issue?

Comment: Without the `quote/unquote` you're basically just calling `test.helper(z, df)` so when you run `enquo(z)` you're going to see the expression `z` and then you run `eval_tidy` on that, the `z` from the parent environment has to be evaluated. So you're capturing `y` as a quosure, you're capturing `z` (which points to `y` but that's not the same).